# JSF Session: módulo de login

Tags: java, front-end, autenticação-http

estou com um problema, com minha session,hj eu faco 2 conexões , uma no meu banco de dados do gestor para pegar o ip e o local do banco de dados do cliente, e outra no banco de dados do cliente com o ip e o local do banco de dados, até  ai tranquilo , o problema é q vou ter varios usuarios de varios banco de dados logados ao mesmo tempo, estou tentando implementar o session por filter, so q toda vez q eu entro em uma conta diferente a minha conta anterior e substituida pela ultima q eu entrei .....

segue meu DAO :

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package DAO;

import Entity.Cadgru;
import Entity.Cadusr;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import javax.persistence.Query;

/**
 *
 * @author Felipee
 */
@Stateless
public class GestorDAO implements Serializable{

    Cadusr retorno;
    public static Cadusr usu = new Cadusr();

    public Cadusr buscaPorId(String gr, String usr, String senha) {
        EntityManager em = Conexao.getEntityManager("0", null);
        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        tx.commit();

        Cadgru cadgru = em.find(Cadgru.class, gr);
        if (cadgru != null) {
            em = Conexao.getEntityManager("MitryusPU", cadgru.getEndfdb());
            tx = em.getTransaction();
            tx.begin();
            String jpql = "select a from Cadusr a where a.nomusr = :nomusr and a.pasusr = :pasusr";
            Query query = em.createQuery(jpql, Cadusr.class);
            query.setParameter("nomusr", usr);
            query.setParameter("pasusr", senha);
            try {
                retorno =(Cadusr) query.getSingleResult() ;
                if (retorno == null) {
                    em = Conexao.getEntityManager("0", cadgru.getEndfdb());
                    tx = em.getTransaction();
                    tx.begin();

                }
            } catch (NoResultException nre) {

            }

        } else {
            retorno = null;
        }

        tx.commit();

        em.close();

        return retorno;
    }

    public String usuarioLogado() {
        String Usuario = usu.getCodusr() + "-" + usu.getNomusr();
        return Usuario;
    }

    private String convertStringToMd5(String valor) {
        MessageDigest mDigest;
        try {
            //Instanciamos o nosso HASH MD5, poderíamos usar outro como
            //SHA, por exemplo, mas optamos por MD5.
            mDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

            //Convert a String valor para um array de bytes em MD5
            byte[] valorMD5 = mDigest.digest(valor.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            //Convertemos os bytes para hexadecimal, assim podemos salvar
            //no banco para posterior comparação se senhas
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (byte b : valorMD5) {
                sb.append(Integer.toHexString((b & 0xFF) | 0x100).substring(1, 3));

            }

            return sb.toString();

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

segue meu bean :

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Controller;

import DAO.GestorDAO;
import Entity.Cadusr;
import Util.SessionContext;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean

public class mbeanUsuario {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(mbeanUsuario.class);
    private String Usuario;
    private String Grupo;
    private String senha;

    public GestorDAO gestor = new GestorDAO();

    public String Vusuario() {
        String retorno;
        Cadusr user = gestor.buscaPorId(getGrupo(), getUsuario(), getSenha());
        if (user != null) {
            logger.info("Tentando logar com usuário " + Usuario);
            SessionContext.getInstance().setAttribute("usuarioLogado", user);
            retorno = "index.xhtml";
        } else {
            retorno = null;
        }

        return retorno;

    }

    public String doLogout() {
        logger.info("Fazendo logout com usuário "
                + SessionContext.getInstance().getUsuarioLogado());
        SessionContext.getInstance().encerrarSessao();
        return "/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    /**
     * @return the Usuario
     */
    public String getUsuario() {
        return Usuario;
    }

    /**
     * @param Usuario the Usuario to set
     */
    public void setUsuario(String Usuario) {
        this.Usuario = Usuario;
    }

    /**
     * @return the Grupo
     */
    public String getGrupo() {
        return Grupo;
    }

    /**
     * @param Grupo the Grupo to set
     */
    public void setGrupo(String Grupo) {
        this.Grupo = Grupo;
    }

    /**
     * @return the senha
     */
    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    /**
     * @param senha the senha to set
     */
    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    /**
     * @return the gr
     */
}
```

Segue meu web.inf :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <filter> 
        <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name> 
        <filter-class>Util.LoginFilter</filter-class> 
    </filter> 
    <filter-mapping> 
        <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name> 
        <url-pattern>/restricted/*</url-pattern> 
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Segue meu SessionContext :

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Util;

import Entity.Cadusr;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 *
 * @author Felipee
 */
public class SessionContext {

    private static SessionContext instance;

    public static SessionContext getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new SessionContext();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private SessionContext() {

    }

    private ExternalContext currentExternalContext() {
        if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("O FacesContext não pode ser chamado fora de uma requisição HTTP");
        } else {
            return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        }
    }

    public Cadusr getUsuarioLogado() {
        return (Cadusr) getAttribute("usuarioLogado");
    }

    public void setUsuarioLogado(Cadusr usuario) {
        setAttribute("usuarioLogado", usuario);
    }

    public void encerrarSessao() {
        currentExternalContext().invalidateSession();
    }

    public Object getAttribute(String nome) {
        return currentExternalContext().getSessionMap().get(nome);
    }

    public void setAttribute(String nome, Object valor) {
        currentExternalContext().getSessionMap().put(nome, valor);
    }

}
```

segue meu LoginFilter :

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Util;

import Entity.Cadusr;
import static com.sun.corba.se.spi.presentation.rmi.StubAdapter.request;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 *
 * @author Felipee
 */
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig fc) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        Cadusr user = null;
        HttpSession sess = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession(false);
        if (sess != null) {
            user = (Cadusr) sess.getAttribute("usuarioLogado");
        }
        if (user == null) {
            String contextPath = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getContextPath();
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect(contextPath + "/login.jsf");
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Comment: Tente remover o static do seu objeto Cadusr usu e veja se funciona.

Comment: pois entao , parece q ele nao ta entrando no meu LoginFilter, e esta declarado no meu web.inf, se eu coloco em cima do meu LoginFilter @WebFilter(servletNames = {"Faces Servlet"}), e faco o debug ele passa, so q ai eu perco o css

Comment: Ah, já aconteceu isso algumas vezes comigo. Usei a solução desse link aqui e resolveu meu problema: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526574/jsf-page-style-missing-when-using-login-filter